# I have all the important stuff in static variables inside of a class and I can't seem to find a way to save it. Any suggestions? Swift 4

Tags: swift, class, static

I am a beginner with Swift, but I have completed Apple's App Development Course and I started a big project called Training Hub, which has many, many things that I have to remember after the app closes.

I have all the information in a single class, saved as static variables, but I don't know how to save them to the disk in order to be able to load and save them.

In the app, the User is able to change the theme, add routines, workouts, exercises, log sets, see old sessions in a calendar format, so he is able to customise the content and I have to remember the changes that he made.

```
class User {
    static var name: String = "Alex"
    static var weight = Weight(kg: 0)
    static var height = Height(metres: 0, centimetres: 0)
    static var bodyFat = BodyFat()
    static var bodyType: String = "Male"
    static var goals: [Goal] = []
    static var routines: [Routine] = [
        Routine(name: "TestRoutine1", workouts: [], type: routineType[0], creator: "Training Hub", rating: rating[3], notes: nil),
        Routine(name: "TestRoutine2", workouts: [], type: routineType[0], creator: "Training Hub", rating: rating[3], notes: nil)]

    static var currentUnit: String = "Metric"

    static var sessions: Dictionary<String, Session> = [:]

    static var measurements: [Measurement] = [
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Wrist", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Waist", point: "at navel", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Hip", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Forearm", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Chest", point: "at middle of sternum", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Shoulders", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Biceps", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Quadriceps", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Calf", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: []),
        Measurement(bodyPart: "Neck", point: "at fullest point", circumference: Circumference(inches: 0), entry: [])]
}
```

Comment: You can use Core Data - Database concept to save and retrieve your model data within the application

Comment: Can you give me an example? I have never used Core Data before so I have no idea how I should implement it.

Comment: Check tutorial online: https://medium.com/@ankurvekariya/core-data-crud-with-swift-4-2-for-beginners-40efe4e7d1cc

Comment: I will recommend to use 
https://realm.io/docs 
It save data models directly in database & help us to retrieve very easily in object oriented para time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your objects conform to `Codable` protocol(for example):

```
    class User: Codable { 
          //all the stuff goes here
    }
```

and then save them in your documents directory with this simple function

```
static func store<T: Encodable>(_ object: T, as fileName: String) {
    guard let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
    fatalError("Could not create URL!")
    }

    let completeUrl = url.appendingPathComponent(fileName, isDirectory: false)

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(object)
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: completeUrl.path) {
           try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: completeUrl)
       }
       FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: completeUrl.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

usage:

```
store(user, as: "current_user.json")
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I have a question. Let's say I use what you have proposed. When / where do I have to save the User and when / where should I load it?

Comment: I don't know what you are your needs so, save when you need. In case of a user you can save data when he modify something in his profile. Basically when you want. And you should load data maybe in the profile page? or when they re-log